# How to add nohup jupyterhub in service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services, nohup, systemctl

Have installed jupyterhub locally. for starting it I'm using this command
`conda activate jupyterhub_environment` and then
`nohup jupyterhub`

how to add this commands in service so that it can start automatically when system starts

Answer (score 0):

The standard usage for persisting Jupyter server sessions is the use of nohup and &; in your remote server with IP address `xx.xx.xx.xx`:

`nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip xx.xx.xx.xx --port yyyy &`
Now, even if you switch off your laptop or lose the connection, you will be always able to reconnect by pointing your browser at `xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy`

[Credit goes to!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835971/persistent-use-of-jupyter-notebook-from-remote-server)

Although you haven't mentioned your operating system, you check this link to run [Jupyter Notebook as a service](https://joelzhang.medium.com/setting-up-jupyter-notebook-server-as-service-in-ubuntu-16-04-116cf8e84781)

Comment: BTW crawler what is your OS?

Comment: using ubuntu....

Comment: @crawler - has my answer been helpful?